# how to get information about PSN ID playstation network

Tags: jquery, api, curl, playstation

i was searching for PlayStation network api but i couldn't find i want simple way to check psn id if for example online , and if ID is exists or not , i need simple why to get any information about the psn id as possible .

thank you .

Comment: try this site: http://psnapi.org/

Comment: i dont know how to use it  i try it before , by the way thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not a known way to get directly any data from PSN servers by only using client-side JavaScript, there are many required steps like OAuth, editing the request headers and a few things in order to perform a simple PSN ID query.
To do so, you need a server-side script to create a simple API so you can do a simple jQuery AJAX request.

There are a few options, all needs you to host a script/server.

https://github.com/jhewt/gumer-psn Written in Node.js by me, the syntax may be familiar to you
https://github.com/ilendemli/gumer-psn-php A PHP implementation of the above

gumer-psn is based on the official mobile application, and it's maintained and updated often by me.

Comment: I'm using shared hosting is there any requirement  to use this ?

Comment: I am not sure about the PHP port, but for Node.js you should have installed the Node.js binaries. Usually isn't allowed to run any node.js on shared environments.

Comment: thank you dear , waiting for other users if they can help i saw  a website have this fetcher

Comment: jhewt seems to be the more actively maintained of the two now.

Comment: @jsachs - which is the official mobile version for PSN?

Answer (score 3):

There is an API here which is continuously developed and works on a subscription basis: http://www.psnleaderboard.com/api

It is made with PHP and it is not official, but it does provide full game/profile data (including hidden trophies) and combines games by npcommid to store products so that metadata, screenshots and videos are included.

Whenever Sony change their system, that API gets adjusted.  Another great thing about this API is that when PlayStation Network goes down or enters periods of maintenance, the API is still able to return results ot your system.

Comment: Sorry - something I don't understand about this question is nobody is referencing any documentation providing by Sony / Playstation about the API you are interfacing with. Do they have their service wide-open for anybody to jump in and start using? Do they not require a specific client key or any official registration? How is this not a security concern for them?

Comment: @Markus -That's because there isn't a publically available API. The APIs collate the information that is needed from wherever it can get it - A lot comes from the Sony websites. The profile and game information is public, but the APIs wrap them up in a way that can be used in your application. How many quality sources an API uses reflects the quality of the data it is able to provide to its users. It's not a security risk because it's just pulling this information from the web without needing the user's credentials, so looking up your ID would not require a login & would pull your public info